# How do I erase lines with different words at a time in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a big txt file and I need to erase each line that contains specific 15-20 different words.

I could bookmark the lines using the specific words one by one and then delete the lines, but this would take me a while and unfortunately I need to do this process with other lists too.
What i want is to delete all the lines from a single move :)

Also Notepad++ regex [doesn't support the `|` alternation operator](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Unsupported_Regex_Operators).

So i can't use Find/Replace or Bookmark for smt like :\b(word1|word2|word3|word4).*\s+

Any suggestions in how may delete all the lines containing my words from a single move?

Comment: Can you explain bit more clear?

Comment: Edited, hope this is better than before :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I agree with **Marco Amans**

Notepad++ recent versions support the alternation operator.

You can use it like this:

```
     [word1|word2|word3]
```

Reference

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of `Notepad++` do support the | alternation operator. Update and try it.